# How to bind variable value declared in an Angular component as a (click) function name?

Tags: angular2-databinding

[onClick function name want it to pass from backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yjfx.png)

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, can you add a [mcve] of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that there is a public function on the Controller named `myFunction()`, this should work:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="myFunction()"> </button>
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can make my function name dynamic i.e pass the function name i.e 'myFunction' in this case using a variable defined in a component??

Comment: It's generally considered a bad practice. but you can of course call the appropriate function inside your funtion call. Would you mind to update your question to a suitable Q&A Format, so that a well suited answer can be provided?